# Java Generics With Any Type <?>

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'm trying to write a method in Java that will be able to add a custom Key object to an array, or change an already existing key in the array if there is one. However, I can't seem to get it to work. The types that keys will use are primarily be String and Integer, but my universal approach doesn't seem to work.

The setValue() method has T as the parameter type, and getValue() returns T.

```
public void set(Key<?> key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < settings.size(); i++) {
        Key<?> k = settings.get(i);
        if (k.getName().equals(key.getName())) {
            k.setValue(key.getValue()); // Error here
            break;
        }
    }
    settings.add(key);
}
```

The error (I'm using Eclipse) is:

```
The method setValue(capture#4-of ?) in the type Key<capture#4-of ?>
is not applicable for the arguments (capture#5-of ?)
```

Comment: What is one is a `Key<Integer>` and the other is a `Key<String>`, how would that work!?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Then the if statement would return false?

Comment: what is settings initialized to?

Comment: And how does the compiler know that?

Comment: @user2573153 It's an array list of Key<?>

Comment: Can you post your `Key` class?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Is there a way I could make the compiler check for that?

Comment: @BoristheSpider To what? I've tried casting it to String, int, even Object without success.

Comment: You need to cast _both_ the receiver and producer to the same type. By declaring a generic type as `<?>` you are declaring that you do not care about the type. You can consume as `Object` but you cannot provide because it could be of any type. If you were, for example, to cast `k` to a `Key<Object>` you could set anything. But if `k` is actually a `Key<Integer>` then you will get a random `ClassCastException` at some later point.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Are you trying to create something like a typesafe heterogeneous container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't guarantee to java that if you provide a `Key` object to your `set()` method and there is an another `Key` object in array with the same name, that they will have the same type argument. So java can't check type safety of your code at compile time.

So, I think, you should use [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

Philip is correct in his diagnosis, but you should still be able to declare a generic type and then use it. In your case,

```
public <T> void set(Key<T> key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < settings.size(); i++) {
        Key<T> k = settings.get(i);
        if (k.getName().equals(key.getName())) {
            k.setValue(key.getValue()); // Error here
            break;
        }
    }
    settings.add(key);
}
```